# tagging releases in ansible and repo name

Tags: git, ansible, ansible-2.x

I was using semantic-tag before for tagging my releases but now I have a requirements that every release will have a name and number attach to it like rel-1.0.1, rel-1.0.2 ...
So if I get that right I cannot use this library anymore because I need to specifically control the tags.
So I use ansible and I found this cool page :
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/github_release_module.html

with

```
- name: Create a new release
  github_release:
    token: tokenabc1234567890
    user: testuser
    repo: testrepo
    action: create_release
    tag: test
    target: master
    name: My Release
    body: Some description
```

Now I am confused. in the repo name if my repo is like: git@github.mycompany.com:test/test-backend.git

then if I just put test-backend.git in the repo name part how would that resolve and work? Should I not put the full path?

Answer (score 1):

It appears from [the docs of github3.py](https://github3.readthedocs.io/en/1.2.0/narrative/getting-started.html#logging-into-github-using-github3-py) that one must use a dedicated method `github.enterprise_login(url="https://github.mycompany.com", ...)` which [regrettably v2.9.5 does not support](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.9.5/lib/ansible/modules/source_control/github_release.py#L185-L190)

As far as I know, the only recourse you have is to copy `github_release.py` into your playbook's `library` folder [as described by the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/dev_guide/developing_locally.html#adding-a-module-locally) and the patch the module to accept a `server_url` attribute, something like

```diff
--- a/github_release.py 2020-01-20 13:12:06.000000000 -0800
+++ b/github_release.py 2020-01-20 13:12:06.000000000 -0800
@@ -145,6 +145,7 @@
 def main():
     module = AnsibleModule(
         argument_spec=dict(
+            server_url=dict(type='str', required=False),
             repo=dict(required=True),
             user=dict(required=True),
             password=dict(no_log=True),
@@ -168,6 +169,7 @@
         module.fail_json(msg=missing_required_lib('github3.py >= 1.0.0a3'),
                          exception=GITHUB_IMP_ERR)

+    server_url = module.params['server_url']
     repo = module.params['repo']
     user = module.params['user']
     password = module.params['password']
@@ -182,12 +184,17 @@

     # login to github
     try:
+        login_mth = github3.login
+        login_kwargs = {}
+        if server_url:
+            login_mth = github3.enterprise_login
+            login_kwargs['url'] = server_url
         if password:
-            gh_obj = github3.login(user, password=password)
+            login_kwargs['username'] = user
+            login_kwargs['password'] = password
         elif login_token:
-            gh_obj = github3.login(token=login_token)
-        else:
-            gh_obj = github3.GitHub()
+            login_kwargs['token'] = login_token
+        gh_obj = login_mth(**login_kwargs)

         # test if we're actually logged in
         if password or login_token:
```